# What are the projected changes in Knesset if electoral barrier is lowered from 3.25% to 2%?

Tags: israel, election-requirements

There are reports that Israel's government is planning to change electoral barrier 3.25% to 2%.

Theoretically, this could siphon influence from larger parties to smaller splinter parties (the example I saw in the news was [Shas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shas) to Eli Yishay's Yachad party).

**Are there any sources that actually calculated projected Knesset electoral changes based on current polling if such a change is made**?

Comment: A poll made when 3.25% is in effect won't show vote changes. A poll asking specifically about 2% will create a significant bias (people will focus on it much more).

Comment: When the electoral barrier was moved from 2% to 3.25% (March 2014) it was speculated that one of the reasons was to block Arab parties out from the Knesset, but those formed a [political alliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_List) and became the third largest party. Since other parties that I know of are older than this and older then the change of March 2014, I think the most probable candidate for disolution would be the Joint List (i.e. the other parties would have not been united *before* March 2014 if they had found the current rules appealing).